# Tensorflow object detection : Using transfer learning on local running

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

From Tensorflow docs, we can use transfer learning for object detection when you run from [cloud](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md). Also, can we using transfer-learning for running locally ? i see that we have a doc about running on [local](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) but i can not find any documents that write about transfer learning when run on local machine . I expected it in [pipeline](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) but i can not find it. So how can we config transfer learning on running locally ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. You can use transfer learning when running locally.

The steps are similar to the instruction on [running pets on google cloud](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md), but your training config should reference your local file system instead of a path on GCS. In particular, you need to configure the train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint field to point to the unzipped checkpoint.

See the [sample resnet101 config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config) for more details. You should only have to change the PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED strings to point to the correct value.